# Sequential start of projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to run projects (MultiJobs) sequentially in Jenkins.

To do it, I use [Priority Sorter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin).  I created a JobGroup, in which I included all the necessary MuiltiJobs, where I have set all the priorities. 
Now the tasks are run in the necessary order.  But the follow-up task is run before the previous one is finished, while I need the task with a lower priority to run after other tasks with a higher priority.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your sequence of running the job fixed? If yes you can use downstream concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj9wcaa7sbRAhUqCpoKHS-XA2QQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.jenkins-ci.org%2Fdisplay%2FJENKINS%2FThrottle%2BConcurrent%2BBuilds%2BPlugin&usg=AFQjCNEuVdTvuUaLRHBqSjpXa8-fo74IBw&sig2=yYE__khK9JKTIIPlwNBJ7g&bvm=bv.144224172,d.bGs) worked quite well for my tasks. I created several named queues; in each of them I limited the number of the simultaneously run projects to one. This turned out to be just perfect. Thanks to everybody who helped.